# How to apply math operations to top elements in list OCaml

Tags: ocaml

How do I get the top two elements of a list?

For example, if I have `[1;2;3]`, how can I get the top two elements, in this case 1 and 2, so I can apply a math operation on them?

Feel like it should be something around `h1::h2::t` but not sure

Comment: We are pleased to help, but why do you not just try it? Testing in the toplevel or on try ocaml is soo easy.

Comment: You're on the right track. Use [pattern-matching](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html#Patternmatchingondatatypes) and deal with empty and singleton list cases.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is an idea, if you want to return the head of list you can do `List.hd list` imagine that `list` is your list.

If you want to return the second element of the list you can do

```
List.hd (List.tl list)
```

Example:

```
let list = [1;2;3];;

List.hd list;;
- : int = 1

List.hd (List.tl list);;
- : int = 2
```

Of course that are better ways to do it but this works to.

Answer (score 1):

```
let hd2 lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | [a] -> [a]
  | a::b::t-> [a; b]
```

This seems to work nicely. But it may be that it could be done better.

Comment: I wouldn't bother naming the tail of the list. `a::b::_ -> [a; b]`